# Xcode's auto layout is only effective in viewDidAppear and this is very problematic

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

After upgrading my project to iOS 6, I realized that auto layout is only effective in viewDidAppear and most of my code expects the view's frame to be available in viewDidLoad. This limitation renders the really nice auto layout feature almost useless for me. Is there any suggestions to help me use auto layout?

For example, sometimes the developer needs to adjust information about a subview based on where auto layout chooses to place that particular subview.  The subview's final location cannot be ascertained by the developer until AFTER the user has already seen it.  The user should not see these information adjustments but be presented the final results all at once.

More specifically:  What if I want to change an image in a view based on where auto-layout places that view? I cannot query that location and then change the image without the user seeing that happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule, the views frame/bounds should never be relied on in `viewDidLoad`.

The `viewDidLoad` method only gets called once the view has been created either programmatically or via a .nib/.xib file. At this point, the view has not been setup, only loaded into memory.

You should *always* do your view layout in either `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` as these methods are called once the view has been prepared for presentation.

As a test, if you simply `NSLog(@"frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));` in both your `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` methods, you will see that only the latter method returns the actual view size in relation to any other elements wrapped around your view (such as `UINavigationBar` and `UITabBar`).

Comment: The problem I am having is that the views have not been laid out in viewWillAppear:, nor after updateViewConstraints, nor viewDidLayoutSubviews - only in viewDidAppear: are the views layout (the subviews have a frame that is not CGRectZero) - and by then it is too late to edit the view without the user seeing the changes.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I can only assume you have implemented something incorrectly as any subviews should certainly be in place by the time `viewDidLayoutSubviews` has been called. Update your question with some code so folks can offer up an explanation as to what may be going wrong.

Comment: From what I've seen `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is often called more than once and it's only the final time it can be relied on.

Comment: I had trouble getting a table view to appear at the correct scroll position when pushing it onto the nav stack (on iOS 7, not 6 for some reason) because layout wasn't occurring until after `viewWillAppear`. That meant the scroll calculation was occurring before the correct size was set so the result was off. What worked for me was calling `layoutIfNeeded` followed by the code to set the scroll position in `viewWillAppear`. Setting the scroll position in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, or `viewDidAppear` did not work without a jump to scroll position visible by the user.

Comment: @charshep- Your comment should be the answer.

Comment: @charshep you answer made my day. I trying call layoutIfNeeded in viewDidLoad and other place, but only in viewWillAppear. i finally fix bug) thx to u

Answer (score 0):

As told by @charshep in a comment, calling `view.layoutIfNeeded()` in viewWillAppear can do the trick.

Quote of his original comment

> I had trouble getting a table view to appear at the correct scroll position when pushing it [...] because layout wasn't occurring until after viewWillAppear. That meant the scroll calculation was occurring before the correct size was set so the result was off. What worked for me was calling layoutIfNeeded followed by the code to set the scroll position in viewWillAppear.